# couchdb show underlying document conflicts in views

Tags: couchdb, view, conflict

I'd like to use a view to compute a summary of bigger documents.
Every document produced by the view corresponds to one source document.
The view output is used to populate table in the UI, clicking a row of the table opens the bigger document.
When there's a conflict in the underlying document I'd like to show it in the table row, so user can open the full document and resolve the conflict.
How can I efficiently obtain the conflicts to show in the table? (all the conflicts for the underlying docs)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the conflicts option in the view parameters, together with include_docs. You can find [more info about view params in the CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name).

E.g. `http://localhost:5984/mydatabase/_design/documents/_view/posts?conflicts=true&include_docs=true` adds the property `_conflicts` to each document that has a conflict.

Pro tip: In that case you don't need to emit the whole document in the view itself, as the include_docs parameter returns the complete document anyway.

Another possibility is to emit the _conflicts property itself. You can do that like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc._conflicts) emit(doc._id, doc._conflicts);
}
```

This is a handy view for finding only documents with conflicts.